# Android app logic

Tags: android

In an android app, I want to load a different activity when the user starts my app than I normally would. So after the user uses the app after the first start, a default activity is loaded, but at first start a different activity is loaded. I plan to set a shared preference boolean to see if the app has been started before. Should I load the default activity first and then check if it's the first start, and change the activity to the different one if the check says it's the first start? Or the other way around: First load the activity that loads at first start, and if it's not the first start, load the default activity.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use fragments? When your main activity loads, check the flag and then loads the appropriate fragment.

Comment: Fragments will provide no additional advantage in this case and likely to make the code harder to maintain

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call `startActivity(otherActivity)` then `firstAcitivy.finish()`, immediately in the first activity's `OnCreate`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to accomplish this (which has a few caveats) is to have both activities in your AndroidManifest, with the first one to be displayed set to `enabled`, the other `disabled`. Then, in your first activity's `onCreate()`, disable that activity and enable the second one:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity1"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_activity1">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".Activity2"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_activity2">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now, in your Activity1's `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity1);

    // Enable the second one
    setActivityEnabled(true, Activity2.class);

    // Disable the current one
    setActivityEnabled(false, Activity1.class);
}

void setActivityEnabled(boolean enabled, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass) {
    int state = enabled ?
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED :
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;

    getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
            new ComponentName(this, activityClass), state, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

The caveat here being that if the user has already made a shortcut to your app on the homescreen, it'll disappear after the first run and need to be manually replaced (although you could add the INSTALL_SHORTCUT permission and add it manually, but I wouldn't suggest it).